# Is there any way to use Timing without the result of the operation being shown?

Tags: matrix, timing

I'm trying to analyze the difference of time when using LinearSolve with different matrix. The problem is that in some cases I'm using 150x150 matrix so the result uses A LOT of space. Is there any way to just get the time result when I do `Timing[LinearSolve[a, b]]`?

Comment: +1 Since using `//Timing // First` also annoys me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is an expression.

```
Timing[LinearSolve[a,b]][[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you! ....

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: putting the semicolon there suppresses the time, too. `Timing[LinearSolve[a,b];]` works.

Comment: @John Doty. You are so right...